# Possible to use select in an update clause

Tags: sql, sql-update

I am trying to update a table using a select like so.  It does not work.  Is this the correct method or do I have to put the result of the select into a temp table and update the table from that?

```
Update WaterRevPropInfo
Set StreetDir = Direction
where exists (SELECT StreetNum,
ISNULL
( LTRIM
( RIGHT
( RTRIM(StreetNum),
LEN
( StreetNum
) +
1 -
( PATINDEX --Identifies first instance of a numeric char
( '%[0-9]%',
StreetNum
) +
PATINDEX --Identifies first instance of a non-numeric char
( '%[^0-9]%',
SUBSTRING --that follows the first numeric char
( StreetNum,
PATINDEX
( '%[0-9]%',
StreetNum
),
LEN(StreetNum)
) + ' '
)
) +
1
)
),
' '
) AS 'Direction')
FROM WaterRevPropInfo
```

Comment: It is not correct.  Your exists() SELECT needs a FROM clause.

Comment: Where do you find the Direction value??? Right now you are assigning StreetDir the value from the same row's Direction.

Comment: ANSI/ISO SQL UPDATE has no FROM clause. Maybe some dbms products have, but no one is specified here.

Comment: In theory, you can use the subquery construct in your question.  However, you have some details that are incorrect, such as Direction being undefined.

Comment: Oops I just didn't copy the from by accident

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exists will give you `TRUE` if `WaterRevPropInfo` has at least 1 row, regardless of what you put in the select. I think you need to do something like this:

```
UPDATE WaterRevPropInfo
SET    StreetDir = ISNULL(LTRIM(RIGHT(RTRIM(StreetNum), LEN(StreetNum) + 1 - (PATINDEX --Identifies first instance of a numeric char
       ('%[0-9]%', StreetNum) + PATINDEX                                               --Identifies first instance of a non-numeric char
       ('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING                                                          --that follows the first numeric char
       (StreetNum, PATINDEX ('%[0-9]%', StreetNum), LEN(StreetNum)) + ' ' ) ) + 1 ) ), StreetDir)
```

It will assign all your logic to `StreetDir`, unless it's `NULL`, in which case it will keep its value (will reassign itself).